# Key error when appending model with the exact same fields?

Tags: python, django

So I have a model that represents an order list. I query this model every two days and filter the result using its datefield. I would like to take this queryset result and append it to another table with the exact same fields. How ever when I do I get a keyword argument error saying "'model' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

```
    time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 3)
    orderlist = BoarsHeadList.objects.filter(order_date__gt           
    = time_threshold)
    for order in orderlist:
        orderlist_dict = orderlist.__dict__
        BoarsHeadOrderList.objects.create.(**orderlist_dict)
```

models.py

```
class BoarsHeadList(models.Model):
    Turkey = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    Ham = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    Roast_Beef = models.IntegerField(null= True)
    Rotisserie_Chicken = models.IntegerField(null= True)
    Bacon = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    store = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL , on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True,)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null = True,)


    class meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'BoarsHead'

class BoarsHeadOrderList(models.Model):
    Turkey = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    Ham = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    Roast_Beef = models.IntegerField(null= True)
    Rotisserie_Chicken = models.IntegerField(null= True)
    Bacon = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    store = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL , on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True,)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null = True,)


    class meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'BoarsHeadOrder'
```

Comment: first you probably intended to do `order.__dict__`. But even then, `__dict__` is not the way to go, it contains private attributes like `_store` because you have foreign keys. And it contains `id` which you don't want to use in the other model, as this could lead to problems when the primary keys already exist. You're better off passing the dictionary explicitly (`Turkey=order.Turkey, Ham=order.Ham, ...`)

Comment: I see what you're saying. Could I possibly exclude that field explicitly. If not is there a way you suggest I try? edit** just say the rest of your comment. thank you!

Comment: I already suggested a way: `BoarsHeadOrderList.objects.create(Turkey=order.Turkey, Ham=order.Ham, etc...)`. Also note that you can't set `order_date` on the copied model because you defined it as `auto_now_add=True`.

Comment: Thank you so much for catching my mistakes, fairly new to this and I appreciate the guidance.